# How to add text before selected text pattern in power shell

Tags: powershell

with this power shell script I am able to add after select pattern, but I need to add before selection
how can I achieve that ?

```
(Get-Content "standalone.conf.bat" ) | 
    Foreach-Object {
        $_ # send the current line to output
        if ($_ -match ":JAVA_OPTS_SET") 
        {
            #Add Lines after the selected pattern 
            "Text To Add"
        }
    } | Set-Content "standalone.conf.bat"
```

I need to add text before selected pattern

Comment: If you first send current line to output and then have an if block, what would happen if you first have an if block and then send current line to output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-replace` - if the pattern doesn't match anything, the string will simply be returned as-is:

```
(Get-Content "standalone.conf.bat" ) |
    Foreach-Object {
        $_ -replace '(?=:JAVA_OPTS_SET)','Text To Add'
    } | Set-Content "standalone.conf.bat"
```

The `(?=...)` construct is a look-ahead - it describes a position in the input string after which the `...` pattern must match

Comment: it is giving out put something like this "Text To Add:JAVA_OPTS_SET", but I need to add in separate line i.e "text to add " in one line :JAVA_OPTS_SET in another line

Comment: @RajendarTalatam It would be a good idea to edit the question and include sample input, desired output and actual output. Then no guessing if "before" means separate line or insertion on same line but before the search term.

Comment: @RajendarTalatam then change `'Text To Add'` -> `"Text To Add$([Environment]::NewLine)"`